# UIScrollView Resizing Itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView inside of a VC. In my `viewDidLoad` I call a method to set the content size. The issue, however, is that it sets the contentSize to 638, but that immediately gets set to 800. As soon as I rotate, I call that method again and it corrects itself to be 638.

So, something is happening in the loading of my VC. Additionally, if I delay that method call and call it .01 seconds after my viewDidLoad, it works fine and dandy.

Does anyone know anything inside of iOS 7 that would cause a scroll view to resize itself?

**More Info:** None of my super classes are touching it. They have a property for a scroll view, but I can remove that property and it builds just fine. So this is the only class I've written that touches the contentSize of the scroll view.

This does not happen on iOS 8, only on iOS 7.

Comment: Under auto layout, a scroll view sets its `contentSize` based on the constraints between it (the scroll view) and its subviews. See [“Technical Note TN2154 UIScrollView And Autolayout”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) for details. Could this be your problem?

Comment: Try setting the content size in `viewWillAppear`. You probably have some constraints or have set the size for the content view to 800 somewhere in interface builder?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why this is happing but exactly this was happening in my app as well.
You can fix it by calling your method in both viewDidLoad and ViewWillAppear.